# How do I make my ActionBar DrawerToggle button work?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrawerClosed: " + getTitle());

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
```

Here I used `DrawerToggle` and defined a function for it but it's not         working.

What should I define in `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method?

Comment: i think you missed `sync()`

Comment: Where should i add it?\

Comment: `actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();`  see this link foe working example

Comment: Sorry i could'nt see any link @nilesh.

Comment: sorry see this link http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html

Answer (score 1):

For Enable **Actionbar Toggle button**

```
// enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
        R.string.app_name // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
    ) {
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        super.onDrawerClosed(view);
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    }
};

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    //mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawer);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        /*if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }*/
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
             if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawer))
             {
                 mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawer);
             }
             else {
                 mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawer);
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

/* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    //boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawer);
    //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawer))-- Im getting error in this code "cannot resolve the symbol mDrawer"

Comment: "mDrawer" is a layout which you are opening (Ex ListView, LinerLayout which is inside drawer layout)

Answer (score 0):

As nilesh pointed out
add this line `mDrawerToggle.syncState();`

below `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);`

last line in your code. Try it

Comment: I have updated my output.On the top of the screen im getting a blank space over the action bar and the toggle button on it is not working !

Comment: i see that you are using Android studio, why dont you use the navigation drawer template? it shall save your lots of time, and then go through the code, and check the code to understand

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work perfectly.

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolBar, R.string.app_name,
                    R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description) {

                /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);

                }

                /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Comment: I have updated my output.On the top of the screen im getting a blank space over the action bar and the toggle button on it is not working ! –